# How to load Total Address collection of customer in magento

Tags: mysql, magento-1.4, magento

I want to load the customer address collection in a custom script.

This code loads only billing address, but I need to load all the addresses(I have 3 addresses under this customer)

```
    $customerAddressId =   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($customerAddressId){
           $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
          // echo "<pre>"; print_r($address->getData());echo "</pre>";
          Zend_Debug::dump($address->debug()); 
          $street = $address->getData('street');
    }
```

Tried this but this is not returning the shipping address.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
```

Please help me to load all the addresses from Magento customer table for particular user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried doing it this way?

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($address->debug());
}
```

Comment: getAddressCollection returns array of records with entity_id, dates only. Not address collection , I want to load all the address for the particular user

Comment: My mistake. The method should have been `getAddresses()`

Comment: Wow, yes its loading all the addresses. But i dont understand why its loading address array multiple times with in foreach. Even i had only 3.

Comment: Am sorry its my mistake. Its loading all the addresses correctly. Thanks @clockworkgeek